# Angular errors during azure devops build

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-devops

I am currently working on creating a CI/CD pipeline for a .net core and angular application.

One of the steps in the build is to use the `npm build` command.

In this step, I get the following error:

[image]

This is what my app-routing module looks like:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { CanActivateGuard } from './shared/guards/can-activate.guard';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { UnauthorizedComponent } from './unauthorized/unauthorized.component';
    import { ForbiddenComponent } from './forbidden/forbidden.component';
    import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
    import { ClientModule } from './client/client.module';
    import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
    import { SuperUserModule } from './super-user/super-user.module';
    import { LicenseModule } from './license/license.module';
    import { IsAdminGuard } from './shared/guards/Admin/isAdmin.guard';
    import { ApplicationsComponent } from './applications/applications.component';// 
    import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'applications', component: ApplicationsComponent }, //Added By Kumar Arpit For Role Based Redirection Functionality
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }, //Added By Kumar Arpit For Dashboard
      { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
      { path: 'forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent },
      { path: 'clients', loadChildren: () => ClientModule, canActivate: [IsAdminGuard] },
      { path: 'users', loadChildren: () => UserModule, canActivate: [IsAdminGuard]},
      { path: 'superusers', loadChildren: () => SuperUserModule, canActivate: [IsAdminGuard] },
      { path: 'license', loadChildren: () => LicenseModule, canActivate: [IsAdminGuard] },
      { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
      exports: [ RouterModule ]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Please help me figure out what might be going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: change all your `loadChildren: () => ` into a path, example `loadChildren: './client/client.module#ClientModule'`

Comment: This fixed my problem, thank you!